# Help preventingDefault within a live function and click event

Tags: jquery

I have a form wizard. On step one I need to display a warning if a certain checkbox is checked and others with a certain class aren't . The problem is that it displays the confirm/warning on the second step after hitting the next button. I need it to prevent the browser from moving to the second step while displaying the warning.

```
$("#step0Next").live('click', function(event) {
        var ask = confirm("Do You Really Want To Continue");
        if($("#RT").is(":checked") && !$(".ex").is(':checked') &&
(ask===false)) { 
            event.preventDefault();
        } 
    });
```

http://www.kinetick.com/Test/purchaseTest
If you don't make any selections and hit "Next" ("#step0Next") it goes to step 2 with the confirm dialog. I need that to happen on step 1, pressing cancel would keep you there, hitting OK would allow you to continue onto step 2. Im using the formToWizard.js plug in if that matters.

thanks!

Comment: I added a solution below, it's not ideal tbh, but without editing the plugin and exposing that `selectStep()` method inside, you don't have much choice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning, *this is a bit hacky and specific to your needs and site* (others finding this, use other solutions!):

```
$("#step0Next").live('click', function(event) {
   $('#step1Prev').click();                                     //go back, hacky!
   if($("#RT").is(":checked") && !$(".ex").is(':checked')) {          //conditons
     if(!confirm("Do You Really Want To Continue")) return;    //user said cancel
     $("#step0Next").die('click');        //user said Ok, prevent prompting again
   }
   $(this).triggerHandler('click');                      //resume normal behavior
});
```

Since you can't override the normal form behavior (their click handler happens before your [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) one), we're just bypassing it.  This quickly clicked the next page's button to go *back* to the first page, so instead of preventing the "next" behavior, we're just reversing it before the UI updates.

Then if the conditions aren't met we're prompting the user to confirm their "move on" choice, but only once, if they click cancel, we'll continue to prompt, if they click Ok then we let them move on and don't won't bother them again by using [`.die()`](http://api.jquery.com/die/) to remove this [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler.

Comment: @Nick - man you're a genius. This works great. I hate to ask for more, but could you just explain a little more so that my understanding is is correct? I don't fully understand "$('#step1Prev').click()" - I get that if you hit the back from step2 (really step1 in the array) it doesn't trigger the function. How?then "if(!confirm("Do you..")) return; - isn't that saying if NOT confirm? Again, thanks a lot, I know you put some time into this, I just want to understand it so I learn, not just c&p! thanks man.

Comment: @Dirty - The click is to trigger going back to step 1 immediately, no matter what.  After that if the conditions aren't met, we prompt, if they click cancel (confirm() == false) then we return, we're already back to step 1 so just stay there.  If they click Ok instead we unbind this handler so it doesn't prompt again, if the conditions are met then we just trigger the click handler already on the `#step0Next` button, which takes us to the next page, make sense?

Comment: @Nick - ok, now i get get what the "$('#step1Prev').click();" does, but it is an empty function the ();? So Im not real clear on why we even need it since we're dealing with step0Next button. On the $('#step0Next').die('click'); that is how we unbind the handler right? which is saying if they click "confirm" (confirm() === true) don't prompt again and move on. Man awesome stuff.

Comment: @Dirty - `.click()` is a shortcut for `.trigger('click')`, you could also to a `.triggerHandler('click')` there as well, any of those would work, `.click()` is just shorter :)

Comment: @Nick - thanks man. I really appreciate the help and esp. the knowledge. Feel like I owe ya.